# "She said she won't/wouldn't come to the party”

Tags: will-would, future

> She said that she won't come to the party.

> She said she wouldn't come to the party.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: You may be unaware of our sister site, English Language Learners, which I consider a more appropriate place to post. But please read their Tour carefully, and the Help on asking questions. In particular you are required to indicate the effort you have made to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The first is only appropriate if the party hasn't taken place yet.

The second can be used at any time. "She said that she wouldn't come to the party, but her friends persuaded her and in the end she had a good time there."